GitLab library build and deploy
I want to build library(gtest) in build stage, and use it in test stage. Now my code is looks like that
stages:         
  - build
  - test

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
   # building gtest at /usr/lib
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /usr/lib
  
  tags:
      - ubuntu

unit-test-job
  stage: test
  script:
    - g++ test.cpp -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread -o test
    - ./test
  tags:
    - ubuntu

But artifacts isn't allowed to add something that isn't in working directory. How can i make this work, maybe build files in working directory and in before-script move it to necessary place?

If the gtest library is in the right location on the ci machine (/usr/lib for example) then the runner should be able to compile your test without the need to pass an artifact of it around.
If you really did need to move the gtest build just because you want to store it as an artifact, you are correct and would have to use a mv or cp command to move them. I wouldn’t think you need to do this though.
